# Remove class if exist and add new one using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a markup for `<ul>` as below:

```
<ul>       
  <li class=""><a href="">Insulated And Extruded</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="">Grille Type Rolling</a></li>
  <li class="active2"><a href="">PVC High Speed Doors</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="">Swinging doors</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here I want to check `li` has a class named `active2`, and if it does then I need to remove that class and need to add different class to that `li`.

This is how I tried it in jQuery:

```
if($('ul li').hasClass('active2')) {
  $(this).removeClass('active2').addClass('active1'); 
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Can anybody help me to figure this out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use `hasClass()` you'd need to loop through all the `li` elements and check them individually.

However there's no need for `hasClass()` here at all as you can select the `.active2` elements directly and call `toggleClass()` on them, like this:

```js
$('ul li.active2').toggleClass('active2 active1');
```

```css
.active1 { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>       
  <li class=""><a href="">Insulated And Extruded</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="">Grille Type Rolling</a></li>
  <li class="active2"><a href="">PVC High Speed Doors</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="">Swinging doors</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need `hasClass()`, You can simply do this :

```js
$('ul li.active2').removeClass('active2').addClass('active1');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>       
  <li class=""><a href="">Insulated And Extruded</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="">Grille Type Rolling</a></li>
  <li class="active2"><a href="">PVC High Speed Doors</a></li>
  <li class=""><a href="">Swinging doors</a></li>
</ul>
```